# Arduino continuously reading ADC value using interrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, timers, analogread

I have a mono jack audio act as analog input for arduino UNO. The microphone outputs voltage that varies in terms of `amplitude` (volume) and `frequency`. In order to get the high sampling rate, I use prescaler 16 and set high baudrate for serial communication to print the value. I save the analog read from that jack audio to `buffer` array with maximum value is 256 (8-bit). This is my code (I modify from the Nick Gammon's blog about ADC [here](http://gammon.com.au/adc)) :

```
const byte adcPin = 0;  // A0

const int MAX_RESULTS = 256;

volatile int results [MAX_RESULTS];
volatile int resultNumber;

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (230400);
  Serial.println ();

  // reset Timer 1
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1 = 0;
  TCCR1B = bit (CS11) | bit (WGM12);  // CTC, prescaler of 8
  TIMSK1 = bit (OCIE1B);
  OCR1A = 39;    
  OCR1B = 39;   // 20 uS - sampling frequency 50 kHz

  ADCSRA =  bit (ADEN) | bit (ADIE) | bit (ADIF);   // turn ADC on, want interrupt on completion
  ADCSRA |= bit (ADPS2);  // Prescaler of 16
//  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0);    // 8 prescaler for 153.8 KHz
  ADMUX = bit (REFS0) | (adcPin & 7);
  ADCSRB = bit (ADTS0) | bit (ADTS2);  // Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B
  ADCSRA |= bit (ADATE);   // turn on automatic triggering

}

// ADC complete ISR
ISR (ADC_vect)
{
    results[resultNumber++] = ADC;
    if(resultNumber == MAX_RESULTS)
    {
      ADCSRA = 0;  // turn off ADC
    }
} 

EMPTY_INTERRUPT (TIMER1_COMPB_vect);

void loop () {

  while (resultNumber < MAX_RESULTS)
    { }

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RESULTS; i++)
  {
    Serial.println (results [i]);
  }
}
```

With that code, I got a nice result of sinusoidal graph represented audio value up to 4000 Hz like this :

[image]

But one thing that didn't work is if I change the volume or frequency (while displaying data) of analog input (jack audio), the graph I print and display via serial plot audio **won't change**. So I had to close it and open again to see the change. The question is how can I achieve the continuous and real time reading of this ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reset the `resultNumber` to 0 after you have written it to serial. and turn interrupts back on

```
void loop () {

  while (resultNumber < MAX_RESULTS)
    { }

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RESULTS; i++)
  {
    Serial.println (results [i]);
  }
  resultNumber = 0; 
  ADCSRA =  bit (ADEN) | bit (ADIE) | bit (ADIF)| bit (ADPS2) | bit (ADATE);   
   // turn ADC back on
}
```

Comment: Okay I'll try that first